# EFI not found when installing Debian 7.4 beside Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, boot, debian, uefi

I am searching the whole time in some forums, but unfortunately I could not really get a solution. I have Windows 8.1 running on my computer, booting with UEFI.

Now I installed Debian 7.4 (basics CD1) on a USB. I could boot find the USB in the UEFI menu and started with the installation. I had already prepared a free partition on my SSD for the Linux. When I came to the partitions he already selected the free partition and successfully partitioned it for the Linux. There was also an EFI partition in the list, I suppose from Windows.

But when I wanted to proceed further, it said: no EFI partition found. Does anyone have an idea, what I have to do now? Do I need to create a new partition for the EFI? I thought it just uses the Windows EFI and creates a new entry...

Comment: For all that are interested: Change the "Use as" button of the EFI to EFI Boot and everything works out fine.